# Web page that feels like native app?

Tags: browser

I want to create an application for a desktop computer, browser based. It is basically a web page, but I need it to be opened in

- open in separate window even if other browser window is already opened
- has as little decorations as possible (no tab bar, no address bar, no status bar, no links bar, no menu bar)
- should not close once all other browser windows are closed
- preferably it should open from command line (linux/windows)
- preferably it could have it's own entry in Windows/Linux task panel, and maybe even it's own icon and/or title

I would accept a browser command line solution or in-browser HTML/JavaScript solution.

Comment: It seems like you are talking about a windows/Linux application, not a web application.

Comment: @AshishKumar, this is a web-page I am talking about, that should look and feel like an Windows/Linux app.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Google's Chrome Apps - http://developer.chrome.com/apps/

Should do exactly what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

I've got no idea what kind of answers you are expecting since this is a pretty broad topic and opinion-based. That said, you have the following technologies at your disposal:

1. HTML
2. CSS
3. Javascript
4. Vendor-specific plug-ins such as `Silverlight`, `Flash`

At the end of the day this is what a web page is all about and it's really up to you what you want to do with it.

Comment: I just want a separate window with minimum decorations

Comment: The only way you can achieve that is by using either `Silverlight` or `Flash`...yet, these types of plug-ins is not supported in some browsers